# Distinct MondoDB function - How to use some criteria with distinct

Tags: mongodb, grails, distinct, distinct-values

I have a situation where I need fetch only distict records which are grater than 0 and all records with value 0.

For Example I have column name called mid then it rows like "0,0,1,1,2,3,5,5,3" then I should fetch only "0,0,1,2,5,3".

**In short distinct record plus all mid with value 0**

I have used this

```
def distinctMIdCursor = dataSetCollection.distinct("mid",whereObject)
def distinctMIdList = distinctMIdCursor.asList()
```

but its fetching result like "0,1,2,5,3"

Actual result "0,1,2,5,3".

**Expected result "0,0,1,2,5,3"**

How to achieve it. What is better way?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve it with `distinct` because by doing so you are defying the whole purpose of using distinct. Instead you can write two queries and concat the result.

```
    def nonZeroDistinctList = dataSetCollection.distinct("mid",{mid: {$ne:0}});
    // map function to convert object list into mid value list
    def allZeroList = dataSetCollection.find({mid:0}).map(function(doc){return doc.mid});
    // concating the two lists
    def result = nonZeroDistinctList + allZeroList ;
```